# How to change value of QProgressBar in QTreeWidgetItem?

Tags: qt

I'm receiving a signal with parametres (Current, total) and each time I'm suppose to 
alter the value of progressbar which is inside the QTreeWidgetItem. 
That is my source code.
I have:

`QMap<QXmppTransferJob*, TransferItemWidget*> widget_map;`

And I add here new items

```
void MainWindow::addItem(QXmppTransferJob *job)
{
    QTreeWidgetItem *item = new QTreeWidgetItem(ui->treeWidget);

    widget_map[job] = new TransferItemWidget;
    widget_map[job]->fileNameLabel->setText(job->fileName());
    widget_map[job]->bareJidLabel->setText(job->jid());

    ui->treeWidget->setItemWidget(item,0,widget_map[job]);
}
```

and each time when I receive a signal there implemented the following slot:

```
void MainWindow::progress(qint64 &current, qint64 &total)
{
    QXmppTransferJob *job = (QXmppTransferJob*)QObject::sender();
    widget_map[job]->progressBar->setMaximum(total);
    widget_map[job]->progressBar->setValue(current);
}
```

Progressbar isn't changing by value but remains the same? Can anyone guide me through to find my mistake

Comment: Did you read Qt documentation about setItemWidget? - http://harmattan-dev.nokia.com/docs/library/html/qt4/qtreewidget.html#setItemWidget

Comment: I wanted to do it with QTreeWidget because I couldn't do it with QItemDelegate.

Comment: You can't do it without Delegates. What problem do you have with delegates? Did you use any search (google?) for you questions? - http://qt-project.org/forums/viewthread/18586

Comment: "This function should only be used to display static content in the place of a tree widget item."
But this part of my source code works:

    void MainWindow::finished()
    {
        QXmppTransferJob *job = (QXmppTransferJob*)QObject::sender();
        widget_map[job]->stateLabel->setText("Finished");
    }

When job is finished I receive the signal finished(), and implement this slot, in the label appears word "Finished".
Why?

Comment: Because label is static content. Once again - why you are not using delegates?